# What could queue up FireQueuedTimerCompletion work items?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, signalr, webapi

We have a windows service with legacy code involving WCF, Webapi, SignalR and more. On rare occasions this service hangs and we do a memory dump and see the following when listing queued tasks:

**tpq**

```
...
31115 Work  System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireQueuedTimerCompletion
```

Is this only triggered by Timers we create manually or does any built-in parts of WCF, WebApi or SignalR use timers and could be the root cause of this?

Comment: You have to investigate source code of these 3 libraries to answer this question...

Comment: You can open the windows service to check whether there is a scheduled task, and then view the scheduled task code in the source code.